# ML Pipeline and metrics: Precision, Recall, AUC-ROC, F1Score

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, precision-recall

I'm using ML Pipeline, something like:

```
VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler()
                .setInputCols(columns)
                .setOutputCol("features");
LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression().setLabelCol(targetColumn);
        lr.setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.01).setFeaturesCol("features");

Pipeline logisticRegression = new Pipeline();
logisticRegression.setStages(new PipelineStage[] {assembler, lr});
PipelineModel logisticRegressionModel = logisticRegression.fit(learningData);
```

What I want to is the way to get standard metric like `Precision, Recall, AUC-ROC, F1-SCORE, ACCURACY` on this model.
I've found `BinaryClassificationMetrics` - but not sure if it's compatible at all.
`RegressionEvaluator` seems to return only `mse|rmse|r2|mae`.

So what is the right way to extract Precision, Recall, etc with ML Pipeline?

Comment: Couldn't find any useful solution, so ended up programming Precision, Recall, F1Score and Accuracy by hand (calculating tp, fp, fn, tn)

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things missing from Ryan's answer above.

I can confirm the following works (Note: my use case was for Multiclass Classification)

```
val scoredTestSet = model.transform(testSet)
val predictionLabelsRDD = scoredTestSet.select("prediction", "label").rdd.map(r => (r.getDouble(0), r.getDouble(1)))
val multiModelMetrics = new MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabelsRDD)
```

Answer (score 1):

once you have scored data, get the prediction and label and pass that to BinaryClassificationMetrics

something like below (thought it's in scala I hope it helps)

```
val scoredTestSet = logisticRegressionModel.transform(testSet)
val predictionLabelsRDD = scoredTestSet.select("prediction", "label").map(r => (r.getDouble(0), r.getDouble(1)))
val binMetrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
// binMetrics.areaUnderROC
```

other examples from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#binary-classification

prediction in this case is 1.0 or 0.0
you can also extract the probability and use that instead of the prediction so that binMetrics can show data for multiple thresholds